# What happened to std::atomic<X>::value_type?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, stdatomic

According to [this reference manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

> For every `std::atomic<X>` (whether or not specialized), `std::atomic<X>::value_type` is X.

But if I try using such type I get a compilation error.

I've tried it with `g++ 8.2.1`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cc 
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:6:23: error: ‘value_type’ is not a member of ‘std::atomic<int>’
     std::atomic<int>::value_type x = 0;
```

And with clang 6.0.1

```
$ clang -std=c++11 test.cc 
test.cc:6:23: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::atomic<int>'
    std::atomic<int>::value_type x = 0;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

The afore mentioned reference manual specifies also says that...

> specification was substantially rewritten to resolve numerous issues
>   in particular, member typedefs value_type and difference_type are added

The [P0558R1](https://wg21.link/P0558R1) specification however seems not to forbid the existence of `value_type`.

Any idea what's going on?

### Edit

A colleague of mine made me realize that P0558R1 is just a *proposal*.

Comment: P0558R1 _adds_ `value_type` and `difference_type`, and since it's treated as a DR, it applies retroactively to C++11.

Comment: The "in particular, member typedefs value_type and difference_type are added" part in cppreference was added by me, and I'm sad that it causes the opposite effect than I expected.

Comment: As a workaround for missing `T::value_type` one can try to use `decltype(T.load())`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are explicitly using C++11. If we look at page 1119 of the [last draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) of the C++11 standard, there is no mention of `value_type` for `std::atomic`:

```
template <class T> struct atomic {
    bool is_lock_free() const volatile;
    bool is_lock_free() const;
    void store(T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile;
    void store(T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst);
    T load(memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) const volatile;
    T load(memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) const;
    operator T() const volatile;
    operator T() const;
    T exchange(T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile;
    T exchange(T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst);
    bool compare_exchange_weak(T&, T, memory_order, memory_order) volatile;
    bool compare_exchange_weak(T&, T, memory_order, memory_order);
    bool compare_exchange_strong(T&, T, memory_order, memory_order) volatile;
    bool compare_exchange_strong(T&, T, memory_order, memory_order);
    bool compare_exchange_weak(T&, T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile;
    bool compare_exchange_weak(T&, T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst);
    bool compare_exchange_strong(T&, T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst) volatile;
    bool compare_exchange_strong(T&, T, memory_order = memory_order_seq_cst);

    atomic() = default;
    constexpr atomic(T);
    atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) = delete;
    atomic& operator=(const atomic&) volatile = delete;
    T operator=(T) volatile;
    T operator=(T);
};
```

It is similarly absent in the C++14 draft.

cppreference just fails to mention "since C++17" for `value_type`.

Edit: It has been pointed out that the addition of `value_type` was in the form of a defect report and *should* be applied retroactively to implementations of C++11. As such, cppreference is not actually wrong, the DR just has not been implemented in the given compiler versions.

Comment: Just incomplete.

Comment: Oh, perhaps cppreference just forgot to mention that `value_type` is available only since some later version of C++?

Comment: I fixed the cppreference page :)

Comment: My fixes in cppreference have been undone, for some reason.  Fair enough :)

Answer (score 5):

Given the nature of P0558R1, I expected it to be eventually implemented retroactively in previous standard modes as a de facto defect report and documented it as such. The paper performs major surgeries on the non-member function templates that depend on the presence of these typedefs. Similar surgeries have generally been applied retroactively by implementers. As a data point, the only major implementation known to have fully implemented P0558R1 (MSVC) does so regardless of language version.

cppreference's target is a hypothetical complete and correct implementation of each C++ standard plus all defect reports and clarifications applicable to that standard.